# Am confused about static classes and instantiation

Tags: java, static, instantiation

Maybe some people have posted something like this before, but many questions are kind of convoluted and hard to understand, and I would like to get at the essence of my issue without going through 3 pages of unrelated code. My issue is this:

When I try to instantiate my class, it tells me it has to be static. I am very confused at this.

```
package project0;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.Button;


public class Project0 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Test7 lucky7 = new Test7(); //here is where I am instantiating my class and it gives "nonstatic variable this cannot be referenced from a static context." 
}

class Test7{

    Test7(){
        String str1 = "Hello";
        changeString(str1);
        System.out.println(str1);
    }

    public void changeString(String str2){
        str2 = "Goodbye";
        }

}
```

If I change the test7 class to static it works, but I feel this is the opposite of what should be happening, as I thought static classes couldn't be instantiated.

edit: I guess I was mistaking static for abstract >.> but in that case what is different about a static class than a regular class. Still a bit confused.

Please try to make answers simple so I can understand

Comment: _as I thought static classes couldn't be instantiated_ Why did you think so?

Comment: You're mixing a *lot* up here.  First of all, post the code that you're actually compiling - all in one go.  This likely has little to do with a static class and a lot to do with you using the `this` keyword somewhere.

Comment: What do you think the problem is, @Makoto?

Comment: If you're going to vote to re-open a question closed a duplicate, please comment first. I'm here to review. I don't just drive by.

Comment: There's a lot we're not being told.  At best, `Test7` is an inner class, not a static class, if it's declared inside of another class.  It's likely a confusion as to how that class should be instantiated.

Comment: _If I change the test7 class to static it works_ The only way they could do that is if `Test7` was declared within whatever class the `main` was declared in. Whether that's the right place to instantiate or not is secondary. The issue is a misunderstanding of nested types.

Comment: To add to the confusion, my next follow up question would be about the meaning of "it works": What's the expected outcome? Should this print "Hello" or "Goodbye"? Independent of the inner class being static.

Comment: And [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class) the bigger picture.

Answer (score 1):

static classes can definitely be instantiated.

Your main method as well as your `Test7` class are inside some class. When `Test7` is not a static class, each instance of `Test7` must have an enclosing instance, which is an instance of the class that contains `Test7`. That's why calling `Test7 lucky7 = new Test7()` from your main method doesn't work in this case.

A static class, on the other hand, doesn't have an enclosing instance, which is why `Test7 lucky7 = new Test7()` works when you change `Test7` to be static.

Comment: I'm not going to say you're wrong, but I ***really*** don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: @Makoto What do you think the issue here?